# Fast 'Record Update' To Binary Files?

Tags: python, linux, binary, numpy

I have 3000 binary files (each of size 40[MB]) of known format (5,000,000 'records' of 'int32,float32' each). they were created using `numpy` tofile() method.

A method that I use, `WhichShouldBeUpdated()`, determines which file (out of the 3000) should be updated, and also, which records in this file should be changed. The method's output is the following:

(1) `path_to_file_name_to_update`

(2) a numpy record array with `N` records (`N` is the number of records to update), in the following format: `[(recordID1, newIntValue1, newFloatValue1), (recordID2, newIntValue2, newFloatValue2), .....]`

As can be seen:

(1) the file to update is known only at running time

(2) the records to update are also only known at running time

what would be the most efficient approach to updating the file with the new values for the records?

Comment: Maybe I answered too soon: are the record_ids offsets into the file? If I have recordId=2, is that the 3rd record from the start of the file? If so, seek will work, you'd just seek to (2 * (4+4)) and write your 8-byte packed struct.

Comment: yes, this is how the file is arranged. The question is, is this the optimal way? will it be better to read the entire file using numpy.fromfile() and then scan the array using cython?

Comment: I updated the answer to link to the numpy.memmap docs. This would probably be the most efficient way to access a numpy array stored on disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the records are of fixed length you can just open the file and `seek` to the position, which is a multiple of the record size and record offset.  To encode the ints and floats as binary you can use [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct). **Update**: Given that the files are originally generated by numpy, the fastest way may be [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not interested in data conversion, but I've had very good experiences with [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) and [pytables](http://www.pytables.org/moin) for large binary files.  HDF5 is designed for large scientific data sets, so it is quick and efficient.